# How to count a channel in mdf file using asammdf library?

Tags: python, asammdf

the mdf file contain many channel with Cha_meas_1,Cha_meas_2,Cha_meas_3,Cha_meas_4,Cha_meas_5,......Cha_meas_15.i want to count the number of channel starting with **Cha_meas**_,

Currently i am doing as below:

```
mdf_data = Data.to_dataframe(ignore_value2text_conversions=True,use_interpolation=False)
conditional_colum = [col for col in mdf_data.columns if 'Cha_meas_' in col]
num_cols = len(conditional_colum)
```

Is there any other way to do the same like counting the channel using asammdf library?

Answer (score 1):

```
len([ch for ch in mdf.channels_db if ch.startswith("Cha_meas_"])
```